# Uneven load distribution after data import to DSE Search cluster

Tags: solr, cassandra, dataimporthandler, datastax

I am experimenting with DataStax Enterprise Search. I have a two node cluster and I am importing data using Solr console Dataimport capability. I have my virtual nodes disabled (num_tokens = 1 in cassandra.yaml) as per "Configuring Solr" doc (http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.2/solutions/dse_search_schema#configuring-solr). My simplified schema is as follows:

```
<schema name="spatial" version="1.1">

<types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="sint" class="solr.SortableIntField" sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true"/> 
    <fieldType name="tint" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tfloat" class="solr.TrieFloatField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="tdate" class="solr.TrieDateField" omitNorms="true"/>
    <fieldType name="binary" class="solr.BinaryField"/>

    <!-- A specialized field for geospatial search. If indexed, this fieldType must not be multivalued. -->
    <fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
</types>

  <fields>
      <field name="id"  type="string" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>
      <field name="objectid" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
      <field name="guwi" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
      <field name="country" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
      <field name="region" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />
      <field name="latlong" type="location" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  </fields>
  <defaultSearchField>objectid</defaultSearchField>
  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

Data import succeeds. However when I run "nodetool status" I can see that the load is not evenly distributed across my two node but is all concentrated on the node I used to perform data import.
I tried to modify uniqueKey to be a composite key, like (id,latlong) or even a just latlong, but it does not seem to change load distribution. Am I missing something?

Thanks,
Leon

Comment: Can you paste to output from your 'nodetool status yourkeyspace' command?

Comment: Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Token                                    Rack
UN  10.30.161.137  66.34 MB   93.3%             7e4bac03-feb9-42e8-ac9a-bf48be32b36a  -8800219472428229728                     rack1
UN  10.157.8.94    52.76 KB   6.7%              135bfc01-a3d3-4a2b-a681-7667f1eabc47  -7564491331177403445                     rack1

Answer (score 1):

Your problem, as seen in the nodetool output, is that the two nodes have tokens that are too close together. Because of this, node (10.30.161.137) is responsible for 94% of the token range.

This is most likely because when you set the num_token=1 you did not set the initial token value. When initial token isn't set, undesirable values may be assigned.

> initial_token (Default: disabled) Used in the single-node-per-token
>   architecture, where a node owns exactly one contiguous range in the
>   ring space. If you haven't specified num_tokens or have set it to the
>   default value of 1, you should always specify this parameter when
>   setting up a production cluster for the first time and when adding
>   capacity. For more information, see this parameter in the Cassandra
>   1.1 Node and Cluster Configuration documentation.

[Configuring Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/webhelp/index.html#cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html)

A token calculator is available here 
[Token Generator](http://www.geroba.com/cassandra/cassandra-token-calculator/)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I run token-generator for 2 nodes and updated the .yaml files. Now I am getting org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: For input string: "85070591730234615865843651857942052864"
  at org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner$1.validate(Murmur3Partitioner.java:182)...

Comment: The default partitioner for Cassandra is now the Murmur3 Partitioner which has a different range than the RandomPartitioner previously in use. (0->2^127-1 vs -2^63 -> 2^63 ) I've put a link in the answer for generating tokens with either partitioner.

Comment: Great! That works. Thanks a lot! There was no way I would be able to do it without your help. Btw, if one keeps num_tokens = 256 as is suggested somewhere else in the doc, trying to import the data using Solr dataimporter just hangs the node. All of that should be documented somewhere in the Datastax docs...

Comment: I'll be in contact with the Doc team, we are always trying to make things more fluid for newcomers.

Comment: I am trying to load ~4000000 records into this new cluster from PostgreSQL using DataImporter. My DataImporter node hangs after about 800000 records. I will try to load the data in 100000 chunks using SOLR console. I am not sure this is going to work.